# How do you change the color for all the items in the status bar in the i3 WM?

Tags: i3

In the [*i3*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I3_%28window_manager%29) window manager you have this status bar. The configuration to enable the bar and tell it which file to load for it is in the `~/.i3/config` file. This points to [`/etc/i3status.conf`](http://i3wm.org/i3status/manpage.html#_general) which contains the following to match the font color I use in my terminal emulator:

```
general {
   colors = true
   color_good = "#00A5FF" #some neon blue
   color_degraded = "#006298"
   color_bad = "#FF0000"
   output_format = i3bar
   interval = 5
}
```

If I enable a status element which doesn't work in my case - for instance *ipv6* - it accordingly displays in red. But why are the rest of the statuses all appearing in white and not in blue like I specified? Isn't *color_good* the default color?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The extent to which each element in the statuses responds to color_good/degraded/bad in the `i3status.conf` file is not entirely clear but this is not how you set a default color for all the items. To supply a uniform<sup>1</sup> default color for all the elements in the status, you just need add a *color* block to the *bar* section of your `.i3/config` file instead ([defaults](http://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_colors) used here except for the *statusline* item):

```
bar {
 colors {
        background #000000
        statusline #00A5FF #that neon blue
        separator #666666

        focused_workspace  #4c7899 #285577 #ffffff
        active_workspace   #333333 #5f676a #ffffff
        inactive_workspace #333333 #222222 #888888
        urgent_workspace   #2f343a #900000 #ffffff
    }
        status_command i3status -c /etc/i3status.conf
}
```

Then use <kbd>mod1</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> to restart which reloads the configuration.

---

<sup>1. Note that even as you do so an item like *ethernet* will show the color_good color from the `i3status.conf`file instead. (?)</sup>